# AWS GLUE ERROR : An error occurred while calling o75.pyWriteDynamicFrame. Cannot cast STRING into a IntegerType (value: BsonString{value=''})

Tags: mongodb, pyspark, etl, aws-glue, aws-glue-data-catalog

I have a simple glue pyspark job, which connects to Mongodb source through a glue catalog table and extracts data from Mongodb collections and writes to json output into s3 using a glue dynamic frame.
The Mongo database here is deeply nested no sql with structs and arrays. Since it is a no-sql db, source schema is not fixed. Nested columns may vary between document to document.
However, the job fails with the below error.

**ERROR**: `py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o75.pyWriteDynamicFrame.: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 1.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.3 in stage 1.0 (TID 6, 10.3.29.22, executor 1): com.mongodb.spark.exceptions.MongoTypeConversionException: Cannot cast STRING into a IntegerType (value: BsonString{value=''})`

As, the job fails due to datatype mismatch reason, I have tried all possible solutions like using `resolveChoice()`. Since error is for property with 'int' datatype, I tried casting all the property with 'int' type to 'string'.
I also tried the code with `dropnullfields`, `writing with spark dataframe`, `applymapping`, `without using catalog table (from_options directly from mongo table)`, `with and without repartition`.
All these attempts are commented in the code for reference.

**CODE SNIPPET**

```
import sys
from awsglue.transforms import *
from awsglue.utils import getResolvedOptions
from pyspark.context import SparkContext
from awsglue.context import GlueContext
from awsglue.dynamicframe import DynamicFrame
from awsglue.job import Job

args = getResolvedOptions(sys.argv, ['JOB_NAME'])
sc = SparkContext()
glueContext = GlueContext(sc)
spark = glueContext.spark_session
job = Job(glueContext)
job.init(args['JOB_NAME'], args)

print("Started")
datasource0 = glueContext.create_dynamic_frame.from_catalog(database = "<catalog_db_name>", table_name = "<catalog_table_name>", additional_options = {"database": "<mongo_database_name>", "collection": "<mongo_db_collection>"}, transformation_ctx = "datasource0")

# Code to read data directly from mongo database
# datasource0 = glueContext.create_dynamic_frame_from_options(connection_type = "mongodb", connection_options = { "uri": "<connection_string>", "database": "<mongo_db_name>", "collection": "<mongo_collection>", "username": "<db_username>", "password": "<db_password>"})

# Code sample for resolveChoive (converted all the 'int' datatype to 'string'
# resolve_dyf = datasource0.resolveChoice(specs = [("nested.property", "cast:string"),("nested.further[].property", "cast:string")])

# Code sample to dropnullfields
# dyf_dropNullfields = DropNullFields.apply(frame = resolve_dyf, transformation_ctx = "dyf_dropNullfields")

data_sink0 = datasource0.repartition(1)
print("Repartition done")

# Code sample to sink using spark's write method
# data_sink0.write.format("json").option("header","true").save("s3://<s3_folder_path>")

datasink1 = glueContext.write_dynamic_frame.from_options(frame = data_sink0, connection_type = "s3", connection_options = {"path": "s3://<S3_folder_path>"}, format = "json", transformation_ctx = "datasink1")
print("Data Sink complete")
job.commit()
```

**NOTE**

I am not exactly sure why it is happening because this isssue is intermittent. Sometimes it works perfectly but at times it fails. So it is quite confusing.

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the same problem. Simple solution of this is to increase the sample size from 1000 (which is default for MongoDB) to 100000. Adding sample config for your reference.

```
`read_config = {
    "uri": documentdb_write_uri,
    "database": "your_db",
    "collection": "your_collection",
    "username": "user",
    "password": "password",
    "partitioner": "MongoSamplePartitioner",
    "sampleSize": "100000",
    "partitionerOptions.partitionSizeMB": "1000",
    "partitionerOptions.partitionKey": "_id"
}`
```